# Efficient way to check for TicTacToe win condition // EDIT: How to check for tie?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

So I made a TicTacToe program as my first little project in Python (using 3.4).

It works so far, but I want to know if it is possible to simplify the win condition checking

```
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')



def playerChange(player):  #Function for easily swapping out players
    if player == "X":
        return "O"
    else:
        return "X"

player = "X"  #Setting initial player
tttfield = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"] #setting up tictactoe field
clear()
while True:

    print("", tttfield[0], "|", tttfield[1], "|", tttfield[2], "\n",
          "---------", "\n",
          tttfield[3], "|", tttfield[4], "|", tttfield[5], "\n",
          "---------", "\n",
          tttfield[6], "|", tttfield[7], "|", tttfield[8], "\n")

    choice = 0
    choice = input("\n%s, choose a slot: " % player)
    if choice in tttfield:
        tttfield[int(choice)-1] = player #marks space
        player = playerChange(player) #changes player
    else:
        input("Not a valid number! Choose again!")
    clear()

    #check for win condition
    if ((tttfield[0]==tttfield[1]==tttfield[2]) or\
        (tttfield[3]==tttfield[4]==tttfield[5]) or\
        (tttfield[6]==tttfield[7]==tttfield[8]) or\
        (tttfield[0]==tttfield[3]==tttfield[6]) or\
        (tttfield[1]==tttfield[4]==tttfield[7]) or\
        (tttfield[2]==tttfield[5]==tttfield[8]) or\
        (tttfield[0]==tttfield[4]==tttfield[8]) or\
        (tttfield[6]==tttfield[4]==tttfield[2])) :
        clear()
        input("\n\n  %s wins!" % playerChange(player))
        break
```

The win condition checking looks fairly clumsy, because of all the checks. Is there a way to compact it?

EDIT: Just noticed a bug in my program. I do not have any tie check, and getting into a tie situation will cause you to get stuck - how do I check for a tie? I have no idea how I could do that.

Comment: If the code works, congratulations! Code reviews are better asked at [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This a great little write up that someone else did.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24764/tic-tac-toe-check-victory

Comment: I have a feeling that without clever reconstruction of `tttfield` you're going to have something that looks like this no matter what... These are the minimal win conditions, after all!

Comment: @Conduit I didn't mean a more efficient way to check, but a more efficient way to write the check. Could I condense it down to a smaller version?

Comment: Looping through the checks for row- and column-based wins instead of having a check for each is a possibility... with your present gamestate storage (1-D array) this may be less readable, though.

Comment: For ties, just count the number of turns. No win on turn 9 = game over ;)

Comment: You could remove the backslashes to simplify the test. The brackets already do that in Python.

Comment: @Conduit thank you, resolved the issue. Turn counter worked.

Comment: Happy to help. When it comes to programs which contain large, important loops (games, for example), always plan ahead... think: What are my loop-breaking conditions (win, lose, tie, etc.)? What do I need to keep track of to make sure I can react to one of those conditions being met?

Answer (score 2):

A common approach is to store the winning states in a compact data structure, e.g.

```
winners = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5] ...]
```

And then loop through them, e.g.

```
for squares in winners:
    if all(tttfield[square]=='x' for square in squares):
        print "X wins!"
```

(You'd want to run this for both X and O, i.e. add an outer loop and use its variable instead of literal X/O inside)

p.s. You don't need those backslashes. Being inside parentheses is enough for Python to know that the expression continues.

Comment: You could also use `any`.

    `any(all(tttfield[square]==player for square in squares) for squares in winners for player in ['x','o'])`